# How to extract common named_scopes from ActiveRecord models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, named-scope

I have named_scope which is reused in multiple ActiveRecord models.
For example:

```
  named_scope :limit, lambda {|limit| {:limit => limit}}
```

What is the best practice to extract this code to be shared across models.
Is it possible to extract it to a module or should I rather reopen ActiveRecord::Base class?

Answer (score 21):

Use a module. Something like this should work:

```
module CommonScopes
  def self.included(base)
    base.class_eval do
      named_scope :limit, lambda {|limit| {:limit => limit}}
    end
  end
end
```

Then just include CommonScopes and you'll be good to go.

Comment: This seems to work for the class-level, but not the instance-level.  For example: `User.limit(1)` works, but the second call to limit here raises an error: `users=User.limit(5); users.limit(1)`.  Any solution for the instance level?

Answer (score 0):

@Matt via [instance_eval](http://apidock.com/ruby/v1_9_1_378/BasicObject/instance_eval), @see [Shared scopes via module?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7323793/shared-scopes-via-module)