# Shared scopes via module?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rspec, scope, activemodel

I want to DRY up several models by moving shared scopes into a module, something like:

```
module CommonScopes
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  module ClassMethods
    scope :ordered_for_display, order("#{self.to_s.tableize}.rank asc")
  end
end
```

I also want to create shared specs that test the module.  Unfortunately when I try to include the shared scope in my model I get:

```
undefined method `order' for CommonScopes::ClassMethods:Module
```

Any ideas?  Thanks!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use [instance_eval](http://apidock.com/ruby/v1_9_1_378/BasicObject/instance_eval)

```
module CommonScopes
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  def self.included(klass)
    klass.instance_eval do
      scope :ordered_for_display, order("#{self.to_s.tableize}.rank asc")
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Don't you think lambdas should be preferred now?

Comment: @mdemolin I believe calling `scope` without a lambda is deprecated in rails 4.

Comment: exactly what I was saying :) (but I think it is just the preferred syntax for now, and not deprecated yet)

Comment: This is also sort of wrong in that it nullifies the point of extending ActiveSupport::Concern.  The scope should either go in a block like `included do; ... end`

since that is part of ActiveRecord::Concern, or we should not bother extending it, since the above `self.included` syntax is built into every Ruby module, and has nothing to do with ActiveSupport::Concern.  Ideally we pick one way or the other, since ActiveSupport::Concern takes care of that boilerplate code that we're reimplementing in this answer's example.  This is for both Rails 3 and 4, as in mdemolin's answer

Answer (score 68):

As in rails 4 [scope syntax](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#scopes) you can simply use a lambda to delay the execution of the code (works in rails 3 too):

```
module CommonScopes
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    scope :ordered_for_display, -> { order("#{self.to_s.tableize}.rank asc") }
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Because your `scope` method is called immediately when your module is parsed by Ruby and it's not accessible from your `CommonScopes` module..

But you can replace your scope call by a class method:

```
module CommonScopes
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  module ClassMethods
    def ordered_for_display
      order("#{self.to_s.tableize}.rank asc")
     end
  end
end
```